# How to convert generic list to generic array without reflection? Type parameter 'V' cannot be instantiated directl

Tags: java, arrays, generics, collections

Here is simplified code example

```
 public V[] values() {
        List<V> values = pojo.getValues();

        return ; // values to array
    }
```

Signature of a method asking for V[] return type, but I got a List. Is it possible to convert List to V[] without reflection API?

I cant use values.toArray(new V[0]) or populate the array by myself because of error - "Type parameter 'V' cannot be instantiated directl"

Comment: `List` has the [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray--) method. You can also iterate through the list and populate the array yourself.

Comment: @Just but list.toArray() returns Object[], but signature asking for V[].
(V[]) values.toArray(); produses warnings. Will this solution lead to the errors?

Comment: Take into account that `V` is a subclass of `Object`. For example, `Integer[] targetArray = sourceList.toArray(new Integer[0]);` is valid and works for a `sourceList` that contains `Integer` values. You don't need the cast.

Comment: @Just Yes, but I cant write sourceList.toArray(new V[0]), type parameter 'V' cannot be instantiated directly

Comment: Then as I suggested in the first comment you can iterate through the list and populate the array yourself.

Comment: To populate the array, firstly i should to initialize the array. But i cant, V[] values= new V[10];
Because 'V' cannot be instantiated directly

Comment: Don't you think "V can't be instantiated directly" is the kind of information you should have included in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without reflection using [`List::toArray(T[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) method because you need to specify a certain type of an array as long as you cannot instantiate a generic array (`new V[]`):

```
public V[] values(V[] array) {
    List<V> values = pojo.getValues();
    return values.toArray(array);
}
```

```
Integer[] values = values(new Integer[0]);      // usage
```

It means you can perform the conversion directly and no such method is not needed (assuming there is no additional logics worth to encapsulate involved):

```
Integer[] values = pojo.getValues().toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but compliler asking to cast return values.toArray(array); to return (V[]) values.toArray(); Will this solution lead to the errors?

Comment: Use the first one, the method internally creates a copy (if its size < list) of the passed array with a required length to place all the elements into that array.

Comment: The first one? Sorry, I'm trying but i dont really get you. The problem is that pojo.getValues() returns List<V> (generified Type) so I cant use .toArray(new V[0]); because of Type parameter 'V' cannot be instantiated directly

Comment: Check out the usage (2nd snippet), you cannot instantiate a generic array like `new V[0]`.

Comment: @Nikolas Didn't you modify the signature of method `values` in comparison with what OP asked?

Comment: I did, that's the only way to pass the array which is used for the transformation.

Comment: @Nikolas If you say that OP's signature is impossible shouldn't this be a part of your answer (along with the reasons)?

Comment: The `List::toArray(array)` call implies an array has to be passed through the method which can be seen at both the method declaration and its usage snippets. The reason I recommend this method is in the first sentence. I think the answer is clear from this point